# How to solve this error SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]

Tags: sql, vba, sqlconnection

I am trying to connect sql server with vba using the code from a youtube tutorial video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWKae1pTTnE), but when i run the code to check if it works, I had an error openning the connections, Can you help me please? I have already install sql server 2019 and I have SQL Server Management Studio 18.

error: SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]

Here is the code:

```
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;" & _
        "Server=MyServer\MSSQLSERVER;" & _
        "Database=master;" & _
        "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    
    cn.Open 'The error occurs here
    
    
    cn.Close
```

Comment: You have no username and password. Did you mean to use Windows Authentication, add `Integrated Security = SSPI`?

Comment: Just tried that and had the same error :(

Comment: Which version of the OLEDB driver are you using? Check out https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/ for more info on connection strings

Comment: Can you post the full exception message?

Comment: I had this version: Microsoft OLE DB Driver 18.5 for SQL and the full error message is: The error '-2147467259 (80004005)' has occurred is runtime: SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]

Comment: I suggest you use this method to generate a valid connection string https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1409.how-to-create-a-sql-connection-string-for-an-application-udl-file.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: Thank you @Nick.McDermaid, It works now.

Comment: Can you please post an answer with the correct connection string - it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that help wiht the issue above was provided by @Nick.McDermaid:

My error was in the Connection string, visiting the link:[1]: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1409.how-to-create-a-sql-connection-string-for-an-application-udl-file.aspx?Redirected=true

It shows a simple steps to do the string conection based on the conditions that are needed. Once you follow the steps that and use it, works fine! In my case the solution looks like this:

```
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;
                           Integrated Security=SSPI;
                           Persist Security Info=False;
                           Initial Catalog=MyDataBaseName;
                           Data Source=MyServer"
    
    cn.Open 'The error that was here disappiers and runs fine'
    
    
    cn.Close
```